# Switching with transistor, optocoupler or relay

Tags: transistors, relay, switching

Looking to make a simple circuit to turn on a 12v buzzer. The signal from the on off switch is 0-1.5v when off and 6.7-10v when on. This obviously isn't enough to power the buzzer, is it possible to controll it as per attached schematic drawing? Or can anyone recommend an alternative. All have common DC power source but signal trigger I'm looking to use has been reduced by a module to allow a stable voltage.

[image]

Comment: Is this a NPN or PNP transistor? Your schematic drawing does not include the arrow that signifies each type, and the model name of the transistor(i.e. 2N3904, TIP130, etc).

Comment: Unsure, I was originally looking at using a NPN transistor.

Comment: Assuming NPN, you need resistors on both the base and collector for stable current + gain control. Use I=VR for base and collector current(assuming constant voltage source). If this is getting too complex, try using an enhancement n-channel FET instead, saturated FETs don't need biasing resistors. However, you must consult the  datasheet regarding turnon voltages, as 6.7V may not be enough to drive the FET into saturation(10V is perfectly fine, 6.7V worst-case).

Comment: Thanks for your help, would something like this be what your meaning? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Controller-High-Power-Electronic-Adjustment-Brightness/dp/B0CC5XRRBF/ref=asc_df_B0CC5XRRBF/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=676204061928&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1526613415033363773&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046734&hvtargid=pla-2272222547215&psc=1&mcid=f08bd987311f34a2a951cf345cd25fc8&gad_source=1 .  I have a very basic knowledge of electronics and trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I was just thinking a normal MOSFET like the BS170, power FETs aren't required since your load only draws 20mA.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's not "obvious" that 6.7-10v isn't enough "power" to drive the buzzer - There are plenty of buzzers that will operate at the voltage, and depending on the current draw, potentially could be driven directly. But assuming you did you research you only need to do the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8fFB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 may be optional. It will depend on how sensitive your buzzer is and how "off" your signal really is.

**EDIT after new information was presented**

Normally, you would invert the signal in software to simplify the hardware. But if if the signal you are working with is a constraint, use the following circuit. This circuit will enable the buzzer when your signal is low (<1.5V) and disable it when the signal is high (>6.5V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx6329.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you I made this circuit up tonight and worked. But I have a problem, I got my signals wrong... I need the buzzer to be off when 10volts are supplied to the base of transistor. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jack see updated circuit for inverted signal.

Answer (score 1):

The 3V6 Zener cuts the voltage from input signal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the schematic, would the components you have labelled be suitable for the load?

Comment: According datasheet the maximum current of 3904 is 200mA so for 20mA buzzer it should be ok. The voltage rating is 40V Vce (also ok).

Comment: Perfect thanks. Would a PWM signal work with this?  the following is a statement relating to the signal i want to use. "The Signal shall be a Square wave with a duty
cycle between 20 % and 80 %, and with rise and fall
times less than 1 ms.
5.3.2 The Signal level of the Square wave “mark”
(high) shall b e greater than 6’7 V and the “space”
(low) shall be less than 1,5 V. The output Source at
“space” (low) shall be 100 SZ If 10 a. The load impedance shall be greater than 3 kQ.

Comment: Also before I order parts can you recommend what wattage of resistors and Zenner to use please? would 0.5W be suitable for all?

Comment: There is no need the high power components. A 0.5W is ok. At low frequency pwm it should work also. The 1ms rise/fall times should be fullfiled.

Comment: @Jack all these specifications suggest to me that this isn't a simple two-terminal buzzer your are referring to. Give details of that buzzer, link to the datasheet where you read those specs. Not here in the comments, edit your original question, please.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done reliably with just two resistors and the switching transistor.

R1 and R2 form a potential divider which divide `Vi` to approx. 1/4 when it reaches Q1 base. Q1 needs a base voltage of approx. 0.7 V to turn on but let's allow for 0.6..0.8 V.

That makes the `Vi` off/on threshold to be 2.4..3.2 V, which is fine for your input voltage ranges of 0..1.5 V for off, 6.7..10 V for on.

Let's now consider the current into Q1 base and the resultant Q1 collector current for the buzzer. The base current at the min. `Vi(on)` of 6.7 V is the current through R1 to the base, minus the current drained from R1 by R2. Using a nominal Q1 Vbe drop of 0.7 V, this is:

```
(6.7-0.7)/10000 - (0.7/3300) = 388 uA
```

With the 2N3904 min. current gain of 100 @ Ic of 10 mA, this gives 39 mA for the buzzer. If the buzzer needs more, reduce the resistor values while keeping their ratio the same. It's OK to change the R1:R2 ratio as long as it keeps the `Vi` threshold within, say, 2.5..5.5 V. You can recalculate the collector using these equations and make sure its then suitable, or rearrange them as necessary. Make sure the increased base drive current isn't a problem for your `Vi` source.

I have used this circuit on many boards in different systems and it has been very reliable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIIIlL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The below circuit will have the 120mA beeper on for voltages higher than about 3.5V. If the buzzer is electromechanical you might need a reverse-biased diode across it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foPXNl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: in terms reverse biased diode, do you mean a fly back across the buzzer? the buzzer is 20mA would this require one? if so could you recommend what rating.

Comment: A 1N4148 will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by adding two resistors and one zener diode to your circuit.

One resistor limits the base current, and one resistor assures rapid and complete turn-off in the low input condition.

The zener diode is around 3 to 4 V to place the circuit transition voltage (Vz + Vbe) in the middle of the input range.  The transistor is an NPN type such as a 2N4401, 2N3904, or 2N2222.  Schematic later.

Update - I see that Michael posted the circuit.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advise, A copy of a circuit would be brillant. Would it be possible to buy something like this as a complete circuit?